# Chart Problem, How to get the legend separated from the Chart?

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart

I am working with the Chart Control for framework 3.5:
[http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt)

I cannot put the legend more separated from the chart, this is what I get:
[image]

Another problem I have, for the orange part (videoconferencia) I pass data only for the 18/05/2010 and the 25/05/1000, but it continues on 20/05/2010, a day where there is nothing.
So that you can see it more clearly I erase the legend:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problems.

The first one is something easy and implemented with this control, I haven't realised.

You can define which is the space the chart is going to occupy with the node "position" inside the asp:ChartArea tag:

I have changed the Height percent to 60 so this does not occupy all the space available.

For the problem where I have data that extends along more days than I pass it. I use a workaround.

I pass a value of 0 to all the dates I am using (here from 18/05/2010 to 24/05/2010), and then I add the real data. Not a very subtle one, but it works.

The result is:
[image]